# Can't create AWS EBS multi-attach volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-ebs

I'm trying to create a multi-attach io1 volume in eu-west-3, unfortunately that fails.

```sh
$ aws ec2 create-volume --volume-type io1  --size 100 --iops 300 \
  --availability-zone eu-west-3a --region eu-west-3 --multi-attach-enabled
```

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the CreateVolume operation: The parameter multi-attach-enabled is not supported for io1 volumes.

```sh
$ aws --version
> aws-cli/1.20.60 Python/3.6.9 Linux/4.4.0-19041-Microsoft botocore/1.21.60
```

However, in the docs it is stated that volume type `io1` does support multi-attach: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volume-types.html

Is this problem specific to the region / availability zone?

I tried it in us-east-1 and it works.

Comment: Indeed, this seems dependent or region/az, `--region us-east-1 --availability-zone us-east-1a` seems to work with multi-attach, but not `eu-west-3`. Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-Attach for io1 volumes is only supported in limited regions and eu-west-3 is not among them:

> #### Considerations and limitations
>
> [...]
>
> - Multi-Attach for io1 volumes is available in the following Regions only: us-east-1, us-west-2, eu-west-1, and ap-northeast-2.

— [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes-multi.html)